# Too many bonded comps of type "IOB" found to fit this device when I design a cpu use fpga

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I use ISE 14.7 and use vhdl design a cpu.
when maping:

> Blockquote
>   Pack:2309 - Too many bonded comps of type "IOB" found to fit this device.
>   Pack:18 - The design is too large for the given device and package.  Please check the Design Summary section to see which resource requirement for your design exceeds the resources available in the device.
>   NOTE: An NCD file will still be generated to allow you to examine the mapped design.  This file is intended for evaluation use only, and will not process successfully through PAR.
>   This mapped NCD file can be used to evaluate how the design's logic has been mapped into FPGA logic resources.  It can also be used to analyze preliminary, logic-level (pre-route) timing with one of the Xilinx static timing analysis tools (TRCE or Timing Analyzer).

This is my cup entity:

```
entity cpu is  port (
RST : in std_logic;
CLK : in std_logic;
ABUS : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
DBUS : inout std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
nMREQ : out std_logic;
nRD : out std_logic;
nWR : out std_logic;
nBHE : out std_logic;
nBLE : out std_logic;
nPRD : out std_logic;
nPWR : out std_logic;
nPERQ : out std_logic;
IOAD : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
IODB : inout std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

ir : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) ;

tABUS : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
tDBUS : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
tnMREQ : out std_logic;
tnRD : out std_logic;
tnWR : out std_logic;
tnBHE : out std_logic;
tnBLE : out std_logic);
signal tmpABUS :  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal tmpnMREQ :  std_logic;
signal tmpnRD :  std_logic;
signal tmpnWR :  std_logic;
signal tmpnBHE :  std_logic;
signal tmpnBLE :  std_logic;
signal tmpnPRD :  std_logic;
signal tmpnPWR :  std_logic;
signal tmpnPERQ :  std_logic;
end entity; -- cpu
```

in design summary:
I use 129 IOBs,but total is 158.
Where is my wrong?
Thanks.
And sorry for my English.

Comment: What is the exact/full name of the FPGA device?

Comment: Also, why are you making signals visible in the `entity` part? It would be normal to move them into the `architecture` declarative region (before `begin`). This unusual usage may be confusing the tools.

Comment: so sorry about that, for some reason(may be dizzy), I declare some signals in `entity`, usually I declare them in `architecture`. But I can `synthesize`, so I think there is no wrong. when I check the report of IOBs, I find `ISE` treat the signals I declare in entity as IOBs.
I move them into architecture, and everything is OK.
But I do not know  why  errors happens in `mapping stage`. @BrianDrummond (I ask my teacher, but he do not know)
@Paebbels my FPGA device is spartan 3E  XC3S500E PQ208
thanks.

Comment: my reputation is 0, sorry I can not upload picture.(This is my first question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am so foolish!!!

I just move the declaration of signals in `entity` to `architecture`.

And everything is OK, though I do not know why some IOBs errors will happens.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

This error is generated during the MAP of Implementation. It means that the selected FPGA board has not sufficient IO Buffers for physical pins. Simply said, you do **not have enough physical pins on your FPGA board**.
If the design is just a module which needs to be connected under a Top Module, you can ignore this error as no IO buffers are needed for data communication between the modules.